# Dired: only one buffer when input/exit in directory

Tags: dired

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired, Dired+

When , in dired mode, I enter (by press `RET`) to directory the dired create many buffers. Something like this:

[image: dired]

As you can see was crated 4 buffers: **Temp, test, test2, test3**

But I need the next:

1. Input in directory by press key `RET`
2. Create always only one buffer when I input in directory and exist/up from directory (by `^`)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), and put this in your init file:

```
(diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir 1)
```

That makes Dired kill the current Dired buffer when you visit another directory in Dired.