# How change directory only in one window

Tags: dired

Emacs 26.1,
Dired+

1. Open some folder in dired mode.
   [image]
2. Split buffer by `M-4 (split-window-vertically)`

[image]

3. Now I want to open `src` folder but **only in TOP WINDOW**. The bottom window must not be change. I press `Enter` in top window. But folder `src` open in BOTH windows - top and bottom.

[image]

Comment: That's not default `dired` behaviour, and from a quick test it's also not default `dired+` behviour; so this is presumably your own custom config at fault, so you should start by looking at that.  However, what is `RET` (Enter) actually bound to?

Comment: What @phils said. Please provide a recipe that starts with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: I *imagine* the reason is [this other question of yours](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36596).

Comment: @Drew When I start emacs -Q, then when press Enter on top window, then open "src" folder ONLY in the top window. Work correct.

Comment: General rule: If the problem arises only when your init file is loaded then bisect your init file to find the culprit. But see also @phils's last comment.

Comment: @Drew I found the problem. I has this settings (with-eval-after-load "dired"
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'dired-find-alternate-file)).
So if remove it then the problem is gone.

Comment: In that case, please either (1) delete your question or (2) if you think the question and your comment answer might help others, add your answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think it's likely to help any future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this settings

```
(with-eval-after-load "dired" (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'dired-find-alternate-file))
```

So I removed it and the problem is gone.